# Does Markdown have a mechanism for attaching figure, listing, etc. numbers to blocks of content?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, octopress

For example, if I want to refer to a block of code as "Listing 1" in an article, is there a way to render "Listing 1" at the end of that block of code?

E.g:

```
public class Foo {
}

                                   Listing 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `backtick_codeblock` you can put the Listing at the top.
This is the syntax.

````
``` [language] [title] [url] [link text]
code snippet
```
````

Refer this [link](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/backtick-codeblock/) for more details.